# SpriteKit Node gives me nil when subclassed (maybe?) to another node | Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, null

Okay so i am trying to learn how to create a game... I want a node to be the camera, so that i can move it and center the view to my player node. When i subclass (i don't know if it's right to say that i subclass it, maybe not...) the player node to the world node, the application crashes. When player is simply a node, a "subclass" of GameScene (and not of the "world" node), it goes "fine", i mean i can move my player (yeah but the camera doesn't work).

so here is my code (few // lines in italian but not relevant)

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

var world: SKNode? //root node! ogni altro nodo del world dev'essere sottoclasse di questo
var overlay: SKNode? //node per l'HUD e altre cose che devono stare sopra al world
var camera: SKNode? //camera node. muovo questo per cambiare le zone visibili

//world sprites
var player: SKSpriteNode!

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    self.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0) //center the scene's anchor point at the center of the screen

    //world setup
    self.world = SKNode()
    self.world!.name = "world"
    self.addChild(world!)

    //camera setup
    self.camera = SKNode()
    self.camera!.name = "camera"
    self.world!.addChild(self.camera!)

    //UI setup
    self.overlay = SKNode()
    self.overlay?.zPosition = 10
    self.overlay?.name = "overlay"
    addChild(self.overlay!)

    player = world!.childNodeWithName("player") as SKSpriteNode!

}

var directionToMove = CGVectorMake(0, 0)

override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

        directionToMove = CGVectorMake((directionToMove.dx + (location.x - player!.position.x)), (directionToMove.dy + (location.y - player!.position.y)))
    }
}

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
 //*these both print the string*
    if player == nil {
        println("player is nil")
    }
    if player?.physicsBody == nil {
        println("player.physicsBody is nil")
    }
 //*here it crashes*
    player!.physicsBody!.applyForce(directionToMove)
}

override func didFinishUpdate() {
    if self.camera != nil {
        self.centerOnNode(self.camera!)
    }
}

func centerOnNode(node: SKNode) {
    let cameraPositionInTheScene: CGPoint = node.scene!.convertPoint(node.position, fromNode: node.parent!)
    node.parent!.position = CGPoint(x: node.parent!.position.x - cameraPositionInTheScene.x, y: node.parent!.position.y - cameraPositionInTheScene.y)
}
}
```

thanks in advance : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your player is `nil` because you are accessing it from the `world` node, which is empty. By default, the player is a child of scene. You can change this in the scene editor by setting the node's parent property (see Figure 1).

[image]

Figure 1. SpriteKit Scene Editor's Property Inspector

I suggest you make the following changes:

1. Create the `world`, `overlay`, and `camera` nodes in the scene editor and access them with `childNodeWithName`
2. Add the player to the scene, not the world, and have it fixed in middle of the scene
3. Move the camera node not the player. The code in `didFinishUpdate` will automatically adjust the world to center the camera in the scene. You can add a physics body to the camera and move it by applying a force/impulse or by setting its velocity.
4. Add the other sprites to the world (instead of to the scene)

If you add the other sprites to the world, they will move appropriately when you adjust the world's position to center the camera. You will then need to move the other sprites relative to the world. The scene is just a window to view a portion of the world at a time.

Comment: i use childNodeWithName because i previously added the sprite to the sks file.
yes i could make it that way, but i would also have to move the other sprites behind and around the player to make it work as i want, so this way i only go around the problem for a moment... and i think it would be more confusing

Comment: yep, now things works. well not perfectly but i understood how to make it the right way. thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are using optionals everywhere.  You only need to use an optional when a variable might be nil.  Are your `world`, `overlay`, and `camera` ever going to be nil?  I would guess probably not.

To answer your question:
Youre trying to get `player` from `world`.  I dont see that youve added any `player` sprite to the `world` node.  It doesnt find it, and youre unwrapping an optional that isnt there.  So you get an error.

You're going to have a lot more luck if you only use optionals when you need them.  If you use them for everything youre going to add unnecessary complexity to your code.

Optionals should be the exception, not the rule.  I could try to fix your code for you, but I'm not sure what you intended the `player` sprite to be?

Follow simple tutorials and start small.  Things will make more and more sense over time.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion :)

- I use optionals because if i declare a global variable without "?" it gives me a gamescene init error
- You don't see the player sprite added because i only grab it from the spritekit scene editor (the .sks file) with ".childNodeWithName("player") as SKSpriteNode!". i don't know if it is done right, i saw it on a tutorial, but it works (when i don't prefix "world!", i mean..)

i would follow tutorials if there were good ones. i can't find one that uses also the sks file(s), which i think it can make the whole work a lot easier.

Comment: ok i figured out how to make them not optionals, i only had to put them "= SKNode()" ahah this makes things a bit easier...